# Prevent SQL wildcard injection

Tags: sql, security, wildcard, sql-injection, sql-like

I have an app which allows user to input their SQL with LIKE Operator, plus at least one placeholder for dynamic parameter, example:

```
SELECT * FROM Usergroups WHERE Username LIKE ?;
```

At backend, It builds **PreparedStatements** and set that parameter based on  current username from login information, If someone can register a wildcard name such as %, then It can view all usergroups.

Is there any standard method to prevent this kind of SQL wildcard injection? 
How should I sanitize the input SQL or parameter ?

Thanks!

Comment: What rdbms are you using? and what library are you using to prepare statements?

Comment: The standard way would be to not allow users to determine the wildcard expression.  Have the users choose from a list.  Of available user groups.  If the user types something in, then `=` would be the more likely comparison operator.

Comment: Re Salman A: There is no rdbms restriction, the statement prepared from through jdbc.

Comment: Re Gordon: the user actually type the sql, he can type any statement with LIKE, but actually he can also pre-registered an username (in such example SQL case, but could be other parameter) with a wildcard.

Comment: @user1684651 the correct solution is to escape the wildcard characters. The list of wildcard characters varies by RDBMS e.g. in SQL server you would change `Mr 10%` to `WHERE username LIKE '%Mr 10[%]%'`. Some database libraries provide utility functions for escaping special characters.

Comment: @Salman A Thanks. IIUC, In such way,  it basically forbid all wildcard use in that parameter. If user pre-register anything with a wildcard, it should not be treated as a wildcard character in preparing statement.

Comment: Escaping simply makes wildcard not behave like a wildcard. `WHERE username LIKE '%Mr 10[%]%'` will match `Yes Mr 10%` but not `Yes Mr 100`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to allow wildcards in your string comparison, the simplest solution is to avoid using `LIKE` and instead use `=`:

```
WHERE Username = 'The 7% Solution'
```

The standard SQL behavior of `LIKE`, which should work on any brand of SQL implementation, is to *escape* the wildcard by preceding it with an escape character. You can choose a character that should be used as the escape character, but for some reason the example given in documentation is often `@`, probably only because that character is seldom used in text patterns.

```
WHERE Username LIKE 'The 7@% Solution' ESCAPE '@'
```

If you need to include a literal character that is the same as your escape character, double the character in your pattern, then it matches a single literal character.

```
WHERE Username LIKE 'Seti@@Home' ESCAPE '@'
```

Some SQL implementations, for example MySQL (see [LIKE in MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)), assume the default escape character is `\`:

```
WHERE Username LIKE 'The 7\% Solution'
```

But other brands do not define a default escape character, for example Oracle. See [LIKE in Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm). You must specify an `ESCAPE` clause or else there is no escaping possible for wildcards.

Microsoft SQL Server adds nonstandard pattern-matching to the LIKE predicate, so you can search for character ranges. You can make a wildcard act like a literal character by putting it inside square brackets, as if it's a range of one character. See [LIKE Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
WHERE Username LIKE 'The 7[%] Solution'
```

Sorry, the answer to your question is not totally consistent from one brand of SQL database to another.